# How to stop pymongo MongoDb adding duplicate data if the insert_one() is called multiple times before the data is actually stored om the DB?

Tags: python, mongodb, insert, pymongo, upsert

I am registering users (name, email, password) to MongoDb and first check to see if the email has been registered before.

```
   def find_by_email(email: str):
        return Database.find_one("users", {"email": email})

   def is_email_used(email: str):

        if User.find_by_email(email) is None:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

If no email is registered or found by find_by_email() the site goes onto to add the data to the DB.

```
    def register_user(email, password, name):
        new_user = User(email, password, name)
        new_user.create_words()
        Database.insert(new_user.collection, new_user.json())

    @staticmethod
    def insert(collection: str, data: Dict):
        Database.DATABASE[collection].insert_one(data)
```

The problem arises if the user clicks submit again before the data is inserted to the DB the whole function is run again and since no data has been uploaded yet the find_by_email() returns None and allows for the user to register twice.

Essentially as many duplicates can be created by clicking submit multiple times before the initial submit is inserted to the DB.

I had thought about using "upsert=True "but nor addressing the root problem. Was thinking about "await" to ensure data is uploaded before continuing but too much of a noob to really understand async.

How to ensure the data is inserted first before continuing?

Comment: Why don't you disable the button after the first submission is sent and then enable it if an error was returned? (I am assuming you can edit the frontend). You could also set up a unique index on the MongoDB collection to prevent duplicate users.

Comment: Hey thanks. Yes both of those could definitely work. Also looking for a better understanding of how the function order runs.